# mixing pixels of an image manually using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an algorithm that blends the pixels of an image and I can bring the image as it was before, but I do not know do this.

I'm using python and pil, but I can use other libraries.

Exemple: [image] to [image] and back to [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to this question? Maybe some sample code that you have written already?

Comment: Are you talking about compressing the image here? What do you mean by "blend"?

Comment: @ThePiedPipes I want to change the pixels of place, doing a mix and then bring it back as it was before, unfortunately I do not have None! Code yet: (

Comment: @Jblasco I mean mix example: 1,2,3,4 to 2,4,1,3 and then back to 1,2,3,4

Comment: Do you mean some kind of encryption where it goes from `normal -> scrambled` and then with the proper key the user can go from `scrambled -> normal` ?

Comment: @seth That's it!, And that's what I want to do

Comment: Jeje, understood now, and not my field, sorry ;).

Comment: Do you need true security, or do you just need a contrived example?

Comment: @seth the idea is to simply blend the pixels so that no one see the photos, I think it does not need much security risk

Comment: Take a PRNG seed. Make an ‘original pixels - scrambled pixels’ table with it. Now that you can scramble the image or undo it as the table specifies. Easy.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it.  There's no error handling, it doesn't follow pep8 standards, it uses slow PIL operations and it doesn't use an argument parsing library.  I'm sure there are other bad things about it also.

It works by seeding python's random number generator with an invariant of the image under scrambling.  The hash of the size is used.  Since the size doesn't changed, a random sequence built on it will be the same for all images that share the same size.  That sequence is used as a one-to-one mapping, therefore it's reversible.

The script may be invoked twice from a shell to create two images, "scrambled.png" and "unscrambled.png".  "Qfhe3.png" is the source image.

```
python scramble.py scramble "./Qfhe3.png"
python scramble.py unscramble "./scrambled.png"
```

- 

```
#scramble.py
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import random

def openImage():
    return Image.open(sys.argv[2])

def operation():
    return sys.argv[1]

def seed(img):
    random.seed(hash(img.size))

def getPixels(img):
    w, h = img.size
    pxs = []
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            pxs.append(img.getpixel((x, y)))
    return pxs

def scrambledIndex(pxs):
    idx = list(range(len(pxs)))
    random.shuffle(idx)
    return idx

def scramblePixels(img):
    seed(img)
    pxs = getPixels(img)
    idx = scrambledIndex(pxs)
    out = []
    for i in idx:
        out.append(pxs[i])
    return out

def unScramblePixels(img):
    seed(img)
    pxs = getPixels(img)
    idx = scrambledIndex(pxs)
    out = list(range(len(pxs)))
    cur = 0
    for i in idx:
        out[i] = pxs[cur]
        cur += 1
    return out

def storePixels(name, size, pxs):
    outImg = Image.new("RGB", size)
    w, h = size
    pxIter = iter(pxs)
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            outImg.putpixel((x, y), next(pxIter))
    outImg.save(name)

def main():
    img = openImage()
    if operation() == "scramble":
        pxs = scramblePixels(img)
        storePixels("scrambled.png", img.size, pxs)
    elif operation() == "unscramble":
        pxs = unScramblePixels(img)
        storePixels("unscrambled.png", img.size, pxs)
    else:
        sys.exit("Unsupported operation: " + operation())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The solution no longer works with Python3. Range changed.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code and tested it, seems to being working again. Thanks.